Sign-Up custom policy upon submitting it it gives an error in the flow
I have made a custom policy in IEF for a sign-up flow for local accounts. The idea of this flow is to sign-up the user and write the user to Azure AD B2C. The IEF policy loads in fine and when I run the user flow I get the expected view. All the fields besides the password and confirmation password are read-only because they read the data from the URL queries.
Now about the error I encounter. When I submit the form I get the following error Unable to validate the information provided..
I have added <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" /> as I thought this was the problem inside the <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-SignUp">. But still the same issue. I have no clue why this happens.
P.S. The trust framework base is the default one from the GitHub of Azure AD B2C starterpack (Local accounts): TrustFrameworkBase code link
Below is my custom Sign-up policy code (TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml):
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06"
                      PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0"
                      TenantId="tenantId"
                      PolicyId="B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions"
                      PublicPolicyUri="tenantId/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions">
    <BasePolicy>
        <TenantId>tenantID</TenantId>
        <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase</PolicyId>
    </BasePolicy>
    <BuildingBlocks>
        <ClaimsSchema>
            <ClaimType Id="email">
                <DisplayName>Email Address</DisplayName>
                <DataType>string</DataType>
                <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
                    <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="email" />
                </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
                <UserHelpText>Your email address</UserHelpText>
                <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
            </ClaimType>
            <ClaimType Id="givenName">
                <DisplayName>Given Name</DisplayName>
                <DataType>string</DataType>
                <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
                    <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
                </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
                <UserHelpText>Your given name</UserHelpText>
                <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
            </ClaimType>
            <ClaimType Id="surname">
                <DisplayName>Surname</DisplayName>
                <DataType>string</DataType>
                <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
                    <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
                </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
                <UserHelpText>Your surname</UserHelpText>
                <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
            </ClaimType>
            <!-- Job Title Claim -->
            <ClaimType Id="jobTitle">
                <DisplayName>Job Title</DisplayName>
                <DataType>string</DataType>
                <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
                    <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="job_title" />
                </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
                <UserHelpText>Your job title</UserHelpText>
                <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
            </ClaimType>
            <!-- Mobile Phone Claim -->
            <ClaimType Id="mobilePhone">
                <DisplayName>Mobile Phone</DisplayName>
                <DataType>string</DataType>
                <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
                    <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="mobile_phone" />
                </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
                <UserHelpText>Your mobile phone number</UserHelpText>
                <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
            </ClaimType>
            <!-- Organisation Name Claim -->
            <ClaimType Id="organisationName">
                <DisplayName>Organisation Name</DisplayName>
                <DataType>string</DataType>
                <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
                    <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="organisation_name" />
                </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
                <UserHelpText>Your organisation name</UserHelpText>
                <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
            </ClaimType>
            <!-- Password Claim -->
            <ClaimType Id="password">
                <DisplayName>Password</DisplayName>
                <DataType>string</DataType>
                <UserHelpText>Enter your password</UserHelpText>
                <UserInputType>Password</UserInputType>
            </ClaimType>
            <!-- Confirm Password Claim -->
            <ClaimType Id="confirmPassword">
                <DisplayName>Confirm Password</DisplayName>
                <DataType>string</DataType>
                <UserHelpText>Confirm your password</UserHelpText>
                <UserInputType>Password</UserInputType>
            </ClaimType>
        </ClaimsSchema>
    </BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsProviders>
        <ClaimsProvider>
            <DisplayName>Self Asserted</DisplayName>
            <TechnicalProfiles>
                <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-SignUp">
                    <DisplayName>User Sign-Up</DisplayName>
                    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
                        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <InputClaims>
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:email}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:given_name}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" DefaultValue="{{OAuth-KV:surname}}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:job_title}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mobilePhone" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:mobile_phone}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="organisationName" DefaultValue="{{OAuth-KV:organisation_name}}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                    </InputClaims>
                    <DisplayClaims>
                        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
                        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
                        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
                        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" />
                        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mobilePhone" />
                        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="organisationName" />
                        <!-- Add password and confirm password fields to the UI -->
                        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
                        <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="confirmPassword" Required="true" />
                    </DisplayClaims>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
                        <!-- Capture password and confirm password -->
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="confirmPassword" Required="true" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mobilePhone" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="organisationName" />
                    </OutputClaims>
                    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                        <!-- Directly use PasswordMatchValidation for password matching -->
                        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="PasswordMatchValidation" />
                        <!-- Write user to Azure AD B2C after validation -->
                        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
                    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                </TechnicalProfile>
                <!-- Profile to Validate Password and Confirm Password Match -->
                <TechnicalProfile Id="PasswordMatchValidation">
                    <DisplayName>Check if passwords match</DisplayName>
                    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.PasswordChangeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="Operation">Match</Item>
                        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">false</Item>
                        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfPasswordMismatch">true</Item>
                        <Item Key="UserMessageIfPasswordMismatch">The passwords do not match. Please try again.</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <InputClaims>
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="confirmPassword" Required="true" />
                    </InputClaims>
                </TechnicalProfile>
            </TechnicalProfiles>
        </ClaimsProvider>
        <ClaimsProvider>
            <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
            <TechnicalProfiles>
                <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
                    <DisplayName>Write user to Azure AD B2C using email</DisplayName>
                    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.AzureActiveDirectory.AzureActiveDirectoryIdentityProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
                        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
                        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">An account with this email already exists.</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <InputClaims>
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
                        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" PartnerClaimType="password" Required="true" />
                    </InputClaims>
                    <PersistedClaims>
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
                        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" PartnerClaimType="password" />
                    </PersistedClaims>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                    </OutputClaims>
                </TechnicalProfile>
            </TechnicalProfiles>
        </ClaimsProvider>
    </ClaimsProviders>
    <!-- User Journeys -->
    <UserJourneys>
        <UserJourney Id="SignUpJourney">
            <OrchestrationSteps>
                <!-- Self-asserted page to collect the user's information -->
                <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-SignUp" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-SignUp" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <!-- Write the user to the directory -->
                <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <!-- Issue the claims in the token -->
                <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
            </OrchestrationSteps>
        </UserJourney>
    </UserJourneys>
    <RelyingParty>
        <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpJourney" />
        <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
            <DisplayName>Sign Up Policy</DisplayName>
            <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            </OutputClaims>
            <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
    </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>


That error usually means a validation technical profile failed. I think you should usually only have 1 InputClaim on the AAD B2C write technical profile. If you configure Application Insights recorder, you could get more details on the errors: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy. Interpreting the data it provides can sometimes be a bit challenging but at least it gives better error messages.

Thanks for your answer ! I am new to the platform and just want to confirm some things. When you say about the 1 InputClaim on the AAD B2C side do you refer to this one <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" /> ? A follow up question would be if this was a default sign-up policy (let's call it so) what would it be missing if you can spot anything irregular ?  I will also give a go to logging the error.

This is how it's done in the starter pack: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/fc39b7dbf7648dcfbcd5d511b49da6583671128c/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L508. Note though that it is using the "IncludeTechnicalProfile" mechanism to include the config from AAD-Common as well (specifically the cryptographic keys element).

@juunas I have investigated but I still can't get it to work. Even followed the above example. However I get this in the console authorize:1 Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'self' 'nonce-XtSxhs7stmU5M8crHIAM6g==' 'report-sample'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present

If you haven't added custom Javascript, that could be coming from a browser extension attempting to inject itself into a page that forbids it with Content Security Policy.

I only have a color picker extension. Would there be any example of a base sign up but only the sign up so then I can compare ? In the example in the starter pack is everything in one.

After I went on a quest to achieve the sign up flow, I have ended up just copying the example from the starter pack and customizing it with my settings and it ended up working. Truly an anomaly but I can see some discrepancies between my code and starter pack and as I dug deeper it's how I write data to AAD. Will post the answer in a bit.

So, after a "fight" to find the solution I ended up editing the official sign-up/sign-in LocalAccounts example from the starterpack on Github: Custom policy starter pack
I have changed the TrustFrameworkBase and and the SignUpOrSignIn file (for the outputs, Stack Overflow does not allow over 30K characters). Basically same implementation. In TrustFrameworkBase, in the OrchestrationSteps I made it so it only displays the first step. More info about that in here: How to enable only sign-up page in the sign-in/sign-up example
TrustFrameworkBase add the following at <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail"> (replace it with this):
 <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:email}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:given_name}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:display_name}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:surname}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:job_title}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mobilePhone" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:mobile_phone}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="organisationName" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:organisation_name}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />

            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mobilePhone" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="organisationName" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>

SignUpOrSignIn
 <!-- Add the output claims you want if you want to reflect it: -->
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="mobilePhone" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="organisationName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />

      </OutputClaims>


MAKE SURE TO ALSO LOAD THE OTHER FILES SUCH AS LOCALIZATION AND EXTENSIONS FROM THE STARTER PACK !!!
Add the following to the URL of your custom policy endpoint: &email=email@email.com&given_name=TESTName&surname=SURNAMETest&job_title=INTERN TEST&mobile_phone=074261984&organisation_name=Org Name&display_name=TEST DISPLAY&
